# Saving value of an array even after a program is closed/power turns off

Tags: c#, arrays, psql, saving-data

There is an array in my program that navigates inputs in database, where to store them.
Problem would be if someone turns that program off or turns the PC off and on again, that array wouldn't be saved, and I really need it saved so it can be used again when program turns back on. 
Is there any way to store array inside of application so my data is consistant?

Comment: "there is an array in that program that navigates inputs in database" - If the array is from a database, why wouldn't it be saved ?

Comment: DBMS systems have solved this problem a long time ago - see [Transaction Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log) for the important part of their solution. There are, of course, limits - what do you expect to happen if the user pulls the power-cable from their PC?

Comment: That array is created in the program, it contrains values that trigger where something is saved in base, in which column. For ex. if array[user_id-1]=1 that means it will make a new input in a table, BUT if program turns off, that will be 1 again, and that user is already saved in table, that means conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Others Told You .. Your App Gonna Lose All The Value Of Variables on Restart ... So u Need To Store Your Data Some Where Before Closing You Application ... If Case Of a Big Amount Of Complex Data We Use Some Sort Of a Database , But In Your case If U Want To Save Small Amount Of Data U Can Create a Small File To Contain  Your Data .. Whither it's a Csv or XML or even normal text File , You Can Also Encrypt The Date Before Saving If Necessary

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, I will try one of those methods.